# Heroku records a fixnum instead of a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Locally it records a string as expected and on Heroku it records a fixnum...

A user can create a wish  and select an area where he wants to see a concert. In order to receive an email if a concert matches his wish.

I have a hash sotred in my `application_helper.rb` as a constant

```
  DEPARTMENTS = {
    "01" => "Ain",
    "02" => "Aisne",
    "03" => "Allier"
    #........
}
```

My create method in the `wanted_concerts_controller.rb` looks like this

```
def create
    @wanted_concert = WantedConcert.new(wanted_concerts_params)
    @wanted_concert.user_id = current_user.id
    if @wanted_concert.save!
      redirect_to wanted_concerts_path, notice: "Ton souhait est bien enregistré"
    else
      render :new , alert: "Oups recommence!"
    end
  end

private 

  def wanted_concerts_params
    params.require(:wanted_concert).permit(:department, :user_id)
  end
```

In `the new.html.erb` file I can make my wish

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wanted_concert) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :department, prompt: "Choisi une région", label: false, collection: ApplicationHelper::DEPARTMENTS.map { |k, v| v } %>
    <%= f.submit "Valider", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my `index.html.erb` where the wishes are displayed 
     <% @wanted_concerts.each do |wanted| %>

```
    <li> <%= wanted.department %> <%= link_to "Supprimer", wanted_concert_path(wanted), method: :delete %></li>
  <% end %>
```

So locally if I chose for exemple *Ain* 
the index display *Ain*

and on Heroku if chose *Ain*
it display *0*

So On Heroku console I did:

```
irb(main):004:0> c = WantedConcert.last
D, [2018-03-04T13:31:54.314672 #4] DEBUG -- :   WantedConcert Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "wanted_concerts".* FROM "wanted_concerts" ORDER BY "wanted_concerts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<WantedConcert id: 21, department: 0, user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-03-04 13:02:16", updated_at: "2018-03-04 13:02:16">
irb(main):005:0> c.department.class
=> Integer
irb(main):006:0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help. 
I did a naughty mistake, I renamed a field in an old migration instead of renaming in a new....
So this may help someone facing a smiliar error...